# Is it possible to inject a process and get the given handles then use them to inject another process?

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to figure out a way to inject an already running process, to filter the given handles to that process, then using the chosen handle to inject another process with the same access privileges.

I'm not sure if this can be done by injecting a dynamic library, that can get the work done.

I wonder if that's possible without affecting the handle granted access,
from a user-mode level. I've been looking for an idea so that i can understand how this works but i can't find something useful.

Comment: doing some cheat and bypassing AC, aren't ya? :)

Comment: lol not really, i'm just trying to inject child process that is not protected and with full access handle stored in it for the parent process, it might be abused to inject from verified/signed module, without traces probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes check this: https://easyhook.github.io/
There are good examples in the pages you can follow tutorials this one might interest you: http://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/nativeremotehook.html